map Jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest to org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request
I want to upgrade my project from jetty 9 to 12.
In the previous version, a servlet class was written in our project, whose doGet method signature is as follows
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
throws ServletException, IOException  {
.
.
.
}

In the implementation of doGet method, we have used about 50 nested methods, all of which use the org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request parameter as input. Because that in jetty 9  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request extends javax..servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, we cast HttpServletRequest class to Request  class and therefore we did not have any problems in the code.
but in jetty 12 org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request does not extend HttpServletRequest.
so we have to do one of these two things in the current version of our project:
1- Change the input of all our methods from Request to HttpServletRequest. This cannot be done because some of these methods are related to the Jetty 12 library that take Request as input.
2- map HttpServletRequest to Request class.
my questions:
1- How can I map Jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest to org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request?Is there a library for this?
2- Do you have a better solution?
3-As far as I know, Jetty 12 works with Request and doesn't have HttpServletRequest anyMore, how does it pass HttpServletRequest to servlets when calling methods of servlet, does it convert itself, or do I have to add something somewhere in the code? I have read this
But Handler can not convert the Request class into HttpServletRequest class, and Even if we change the request, it will be Request class type, not HttpServletRequest class type

The signature you mentioned ...
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
throws ServletException, IOException {
}

That is from jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet
As evidenced from the official codebase ...
https://github.com/jakartaee/servlet/blob/6.0.0-RELEASE/api/src/main/java/jakarta/servlet/http/HttpServlet.java#L162-L166
If you use Jetty 12's ee10 environment you'll have access the the Servlet 6.0 API.
Including the ServletContextHandler you can use to add Servlets / Filters.

but in jetty 12 org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request does not extend
HttpServletRequest. so we have to do one of these two things in the
current version of our project:

Jetty 12 core has no Servlet, correct.
But Jetty 12 supports multiple Servlet environments (ee10, ee9, and ee8 with Jetty 12.0.x, and soon ee11 with Jetty 12.1.x)
You made a HUGE jump going from Jetty 9 to Jetty 12.
You have none of the years of adoption from Jetty 9 behaviors to what is now in Jetty 12.
You have a lot of work ahead of you.

1- Change the input of all our methods from Request to
HttpServletRequest. This cannot be done because some of these methods
are related to the Jetty 12 library that take Request as input.

Use the HttpServletRequest, there should be nothing in the core Request object that isn't available in the HttpServletRequest (especially considering you are moving from Jetty 9)
Wait? are you using Handlers from Jetty 9?
If so, then DO NOT USE HttpServletRequest and use standard Request objects.

2- map HttpServletRequest to Request class.

Not a good idea, as HttpServletRequest requires a ServletContext, which you also do not have if you use Core features.

my questions:
1- How can I map Jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest to
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request? Is there a library for this?

No, do not do this, you will have to replicate the entire ServletContext and associated handling in Servlet just to have an API that is HttpServletRequest.

2- Do you have a better solution?

Pick a side, either go Jetty Core and no Servlet, or go Jetty 12 ee10 environment and only Servlet, don't mix-n-match in the same handling.
That being said, you can have separate behaviors, some Jetty Core Handlers, and some Jetty ee10 environment Servlet 6.0 servlets / filters.

3-As far as I know, Jetty 12 works with Request and doesn't have
HttpServletRequest anyMore, how does it pass HttpServletRequest to
servlets when calling methods of servlet, does it convert itself, or
do I have to add something somewhere in the code? I have read this But
Handler can not convert the Request class into HttpServletRequest
class, and Even if we change the request, it will be Request class
type, not HttpServletRequest class type

HttpServletRequest is present in the ee environments (ee10, ee9, ee8, etc).
Check the github.com/jetty/jetty-examples Jetty 12  branch "embedded" examples for some inspiration (and example projects that use the ee environments and their dependencies)

Actually, this is my main problem:
In the implementation of our project servlet, the method '
login(String username, Object credentials, Request request, Function<Boolean,Session> getOrCreateSession)' from org.eclipse.jetty.security.LoginService is called, How do I convert HttpServletRequest that I received as input of the servlet method into  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request that I can pass to LoginService.login() method? How do I initialize org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request to send to this method? @Joakim

That's a new question, and best asked at the Jetty issue tracker - https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues
